# Magento2 Back End is working fine but front end is not working and showing This page isn’t working error

Tags: magento2, product, error, collection, variables

I am working on a Magento 2 project, and it was working fine until today, but now when I try to open it, the page is not working.

The following error is coming in error log:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection::addIsSaleableAttributeToFilter()
>   must be of the type array or null, integer given, called in
>   /home/olfwmbaph2hf/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Collection.php
>   on line 1582 and defined in
>   /home/olfwmbaph2hf/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Collection.php:2475

can someone help to resolve this issue as soon as possible

Comment: can you please share the code which you working on

Comment: back end is not working after login to Magento admin version 2.3.4